# Reduce an array of array into a single array with flattening in f#

Tags: f#

If I have the following

```
type Merchant = {
    Id:int;
    OtherItems:int[] }


let (merchant1:Merchant) = {
    Id = 1;
    OtherItems = [| 1; 2 |]}

let (merchant2:Merchant) = {
    Id = 2;
    OtherItems = [| 1; 2 |]}


let merchants = [| merchant1;merchant2|]
```

And I want to flatten to the following, how do I do it?

```
Id = 1 OtherItems 1  
Id = 1 OtherItems 2 
Id = 2 OtherItems 1  
Id = 2 OtherItems 2
```

This is what I have come up with but cant seem to get any further

```
let x = 
    merchants
     |> Array.map(fun merchant -> merchant, merchant.OtherItems)
```

Note: I could do the long way in c# oo style but want to use functional way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way using `Array.collect`:

```
let x =
    merchants
    |> Array.collect (fun m ->
        m.OtherItems
        |> Array.map (fun x -> { Id = m.Id; OtherItems = [|x|] }))
```

You could make this easier to understand my first introducing a function that flattens a single merchant:

```
let flatten merchant = [|
    for x in merchant.OtherItems do
        yield { Id = merchant.Id; OtherItems = [|x|] } |]
```

This function has the type `Merchant -> Merchant []`, so it turns a single merchant into an array of merchants, one for each `OtherItems`.

With that `flatten` function, you can use the standard, built-in `collect` function to flatten an array of merchants:

```
let x' = merchants |> Array.collect flatten
```

Both options produce this result:

```
[|
    {Id = 1; OtherItems = [|1|];};
    {Id = 1; OtherItems = [|2|];};
    {Id = 2; OtherItems = [|1|];};
    {Id = 2; OtherItems = [|2|];}
|]
```

Comment: mark , this worked for me in script file but when i put into fs file I get "the record label "Id" is not defined"

Comment: @Noel How do I repro that?

Answer (score 4):

Use sequence generation:

```
let mySequence =
    seq {
        for merchant in merchants do
            for otherItem in merchant.OtherItems do
                yield {Id=merchant.Id; OtherItems=[|otherItem|]}
    }
```

or array generation

```
let myArray =
    [|
        for merchant in merchants do
            for otherItem in merchant.OtherItems do
                yield {Id=merchant.Id; OtherItems= [|otherItem|]}
    |]
```